# ERROR: Method does not override method from its superclass

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Este es el error que me aparece]Tengo este problema y la verdad no sé cómo empezar a resolverlo siquiera. He revisado preguntas parecidas y todas son debido a errores de ortografía (ponen OnCreate en vez de onCreate, por ejemplo).

```
public class LibSimilares extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {


private Toolbar toolbar;
TextView textView;
private String id_g;
private JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
ArrayList<datg> ListBook;
RecyclerView recyclerlibros;

private void findAllViewsById()
{
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.libsimilares);

    findAllViewsById();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_item_book, container, false);
    ListBook = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerlibros = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.Rvrecyclerview);
    recyclerlibros.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));

    dato();

    return view;
}

public void dato(){
    Bundle dat = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    id_g = dat.getString("IDG");
    RecibirDatos(id_g);
}

public void RecibirDatos(String ID_G){
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+TAGID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String url = "https://inbook345.000webhostapp.com/InBook/consultagenero.php?idg=" + ID_G;
    jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, menu);

    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.buscar);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    //permite modificar el hint que el EditText muestra por defecto
    searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.buscar));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Toast.makeText(PantallaPrincipal.this, R.string.submitted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //se oculta el EditText
            searchView.setQuery("", false);
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //textView.setText(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No se pudo Consultar "+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("ERROR",error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    datg dat = null;

    JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("genero");

    try{
        for (int i=0; i<json.length(); i++){
            dat = new datg();
            JSONObject jsonObject= null;
            jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);

            jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(json.length());
            dat.setTitulo(jsonObject.optString("TITULO"));
            dat.setDatg(jsonObject.optString("IMAGEN"));
            ListBook.add(dat);
        }

        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,ListBook);
        recyclerlibros.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Me manda error en el onCreateView. De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el error?

Comment: El error es el del título. Aprece una rayita roja subrrayando el @Override del onCreateView, y al poner el cursor sobre la raayita aparece el error del título de la pregunta.

Comment: ¿No te falta un parámetro en el método? :  `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {`  revisa la [documentación del método](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)).

Comment: De acuerdo con @A.Cedano, es lo único que se ve.

Comment: Ya añadí el parámetro y continúa el error

Comment: Muestra la traza completa del error editando la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Así?

Comment: @Alders el método onCreateView() que tratas de usar es para un Fragment no una Activity, es por eso que tienes este problema.

Comment: La traza del error es el mensaje completo del error, que suele ser un mensaje largo que muestra todo el recorrido del código hasta llegar al error. Para verlo tienes que hacer click en la pestaña `Event Log` que suele estar en la parte inferior derecha y luego en la opción `LogCat` que es una de las que aparecen  también abajo (a la izquierda)  cuando activas `Event Log`. De todos modos verifica lo que te ha dicho @Jorgesys en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el método `onCreateView()` que tratas de usar sobre escribe un método de la clase `Fragment` y tu clase en realidad es una `Activity`, este método no puede ser usado dentro de LibSimilares.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tratas de agregar este método se generara un aviso en tu clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los métodos `onCreateView()` que puedes usar dentro de una `Activity` tienen esta forma:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```